# I want to Remove glyphicon-ok from Submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a Registration Form. I have applied Jquery with the help of ID of the element. When I click the submit button I also got glyphicon-ok at submit button, whick i dont want to happen. Simply copy the code and past it in html file on your PC....

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form Validation</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function validateText(id)
    {
        if($("#"+id).val()==null || $("#"+id).val()=="")
        {
            var div = $("#"+id).closest("div");
            div.removeClass("has-success");
            $("#glypcn"+id).remove();

            div.addClass("has-error has-feedback");
            div.append('<span id="glypcn'+id+'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>')
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            var div = $("#"+id).closest("div");
            div.removeClass("has-error");
            div.addClass("has-feedback has-success");
            $("#glypcn"+id).remove();
            div.append('<span id="glypcn'+id+'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>')
            return true;
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function ()
            {
                $("#btn1").click(function ()
                {
                    validateText("firstname");

                    validateText("lastname");

                    validateText("username");

                    validateText("password");

                    validateText("cpassword");

                    validateText("date");

                    validateText("male");

                    validateText("female");

                    $("register-form").submit();
                });

            }
    );
</script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <script src="static/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--<script src="C:/Users/DA_YALS/Desktop/fv/static/combodate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="height:auto; border:solid black;">
                    <form method="post" role="form" id="register-form" autocomplete="off">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name"  type="text" required="required">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" name="lastname" required="required" >
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="username">Username:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" type="text" id="username" name="username" required="required">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Password:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" type="password" id="password" name="password" required="required">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="cpassword">Confirm Password:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" type="password" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" required="required">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="date" id="text">Date of Birth:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="date" name="date" data-format="DD-MM-YYYY" data-template="D MMM YYYY" name="date" value="09-01-2013" required="required">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" style="border: solid;">
                            <label id="gender">Gender:</label>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input id="male" type="radio" name="Male" checked>Male</label>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input id="female" type="radio" name="Female">Female</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" >
                            <button class="btn btn-success" id="btn1" type="submit">Submit</button>
                        </div>

                    </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Umm you add that in your js Code. Probably yiu are New at this because yiu could just read the Code and find it out by yourself. Anyways remove this Line div.append('<span id="glypcn'+id+'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>')

Answer (score 0):

The icon is not applied on the submit buttons but on the radios.

So you have to modify your `validateText` function to not add the icon on radio buttons:

```
function validateText(id)
{
    if($("#"+id).val()==null || $("#"+id).val()=="")
    {
        var div = $("#"+id).closest("div");
        div.removeClass("has-success");
        $("#glypcn"+id).remove();
        div.addClass("has-error has-feedback");
        if (!($("#"+id).is(':checkbox') || $("#"+id).is(':radio'))) {
            div.append('<span id="glypcn'+id+'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
        }
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        var div = $("#"+id).closest("div");
        div.removeClass("has-error");
        div.addClass("has-feedback has-success");
        $("#glypcn"+id).remove();
        if (!($("#"+id).is(':checkbox') || $("#"+id).is(':radio'))) {
            div.append('<span id="glypcn'+id+'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```